# Facebook Page Plugin - Custom Message When no Upcoming Events

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a question about the Facebook Page plugin that I'm using to display events. When there are no upcoming events, "[Group Name] does not have any upcoming events." is displayed. However, I would like to display a different message. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

> However, I would like to display a different message. Is that possible?

No, that is not possible.

Your options to influence the Facebook social plugins are limited to the parameters described in the documentation, and there isn’t one to specifically change that message.